# JavaScript onerror and onload browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload, onerror

I am using JavaScript's `element.onload` and `element.onerror` functions after I add elements to the DOM. Now I'm interested in the browser compatibility for this methods because I saw some people using `element.onreadystatechange`.

How can I define a function for onload and onerror so that it isvalid on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to be valid in all browsers (assuming this includes older ones like IE7) is to use a framework like dojo or jquery to handle the abstraction for you.

However to answer you question about the browser compatibility of `onload` and `onerror` the main issue is that they don't fire in IE8 and below if the page is already loaded.

I wouldn't recommend `onreadystatechange` as it isn't a standard for all browsers and won't be available in the future:

[Won't be supportted from IE11 onwards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you please provide a code example to handle all modern browsers and IE8+ with onerror and onload function!?